# How to convert application URI to normal file path?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

How can I obtain normal file path from application URI given that I'm aware of application / package id?

> ms-appx:///assets/Logo.png
>   ms-appdata:///local/Packs/area1.dat

`PathCreateFromUrlW` obviously does not work. I think for UWP applications there is a crippled method to obtain a path for *current* application by creating an instance of storage file object using `IStorageFileStatics::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` and then invoking `IStorageItem::get_Path`.

Comment: Whatever you are going to do next is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround:

You can use [GetPackagePathByFullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/AppModel/nf-appmodel-getpackagepathbyfullname) to get the UWP application install path using [PACKAGE_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/appmodel/ns-appmodel-package_id).
The path will like this `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SDKSamples.ListView.CS_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\`.

If you want a path of file under assets the path will be `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SDKSamples.ListView.CS_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets\Logo.png`

Sample code:

```
GetPackagePathByFullName(L"Microsoft.SDKSamples.ListView.CS_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe", &path, buffer);
```

More reference: "[Package query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/functions)"